# jquery:I want to make a particular table row readonly based on column td value. the td values have textboxes embedded into it using mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
        var $row = $(this).closest("tr");      // Finds the closest row <tr>
        ($row).attr("readonly", true);
```

I have to make table rows readonly based on td value or hidden field inside the table.kindly help

Comment: try `$row.find("input,button,textarea,select").attr("disabled", "disabled");`

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one:

```
$(function() {
  $('table tr').each(function() {
    $(this).find('td').each(function() {
        $(this).find('input,select,textarea').attr("readonly", true);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Have you checked this? @Prabhu